# rails-3.2.1 scaffold generator try to include blueprints.rb spec support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

Running the generator, it try to append spec/support/blueprints.rb, than fails :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/trends$ rails g scaffold trends 
Plural version of the model detected, using singularized version. Override with --force-plural.
      invoke  mongoid
      create    app/models/trend.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/trend_spec.rb
      invoke      machinist
      append        spec/support/blueprints.rb
/home/lsoave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails-3.2.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/inject_into_file.rb:99:in `binread': No such file or directory - /home/lsoave/rails/github/trends/spec/support/blueprints.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
```

How can I get rid of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaffold is looking to append a new machinist factory to blueprints.rb.  This is likely because you've configured your generator to use machinist instead of a fixture.  Just create the file, or change your generator config not to use Machinist.

Also, when you generate scaffolding, you should use the singular name of the model, so :

```
rails g scaffold trend
```